# Crypto++ what to do with the IV

Tags: objective-c, cryptography, initialization-vector

So I'm trying to use encryption from Crypto++ in a Objective-C project.
The problem in what to do with the IV? I try to pre-append it to the ciphertext. But then I have a problem recovering it for decryption.

Here is the code:

```
- (NSString *)encryptUsingSerpentWithPlaintext:(NSString *)plaintext andKey:(NSData *)keyData
{
    std::string ptext = [plaintext UTF8String];
    std::string ciphertext;

    byte key[ CryptoPP::Serpent::MAX_KEYLENGTH ], iv[ CryptoPP::Serpent::BLOCKSIZE ];

    CryptoPP::AutoSeededX917RNG<CryptoPP::Serpent> rng;
    rng.GenerateBlock(iv, CryptoPP::Serpent::BLOCKSIZE);

    std::string ivs(reinterpret_cast<char const *>(iv));
    lcl_log(lcl_cCrypto, lcl_vDebug, @"Random IV:%s",ivs.c_str());


    ::memcpy(key, keyData.bytes, keyData.length);


    CryptoPP::Serpent::Encryption serpentEncryptor (key, CryptoPP::Serpent::MAX_KEYLENGTH);
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcSerpentEncryptor (serpentEncryptor, iv);

    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfSerpentEncryptor(cbcSerpentEncryptor, new CryptoPP::StringSink (ciphertext));
    stfSerpentEncryptor.Put( reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>( ptext.c_str() ), ptext.length() + 1);
    stfSerpentEncryptor.MessageEnd();

    lcl_log(lcl_cCrypto, lcl_vDebug, @"Non-Encoded ciphertext [size:%lu]:%s",sizeof(ciphertext),ciphertext.c_str());

    std::string finalCT;

    ciphertext = ivs + ciphertext; // add the IV before the ciphertext

    lcl_log(lcl_cCrypto, lcl_vDebug, @"Non-Encoded iv+ciphertext [size:%lu]:%s",sizeof(ciphertext),ciphertext.c_str());

    CryptoPP::StringSource base64Encoder (ciphertext, true, new CryptoPP::Base64Encoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(finalCT)));

    // apply HMAC
    // TO DO

    NSString *cryptogram = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:finalCT.c_str()];

    return cryptogram;
}

- (NSString *)decryptUsingSerpentWithCiphertext:(NSString *)ciphertext andKey:(NSData *)keyData
{
    std::string ctext;
    std::string plaintext;

    byte key[ CryptoPP::Serpent::MAX_KEYLENGTH ], iv[ CryptoPP::Serpent::BLOCKSIZE ];

    ::memcpy(key, keyData.bytes, keyData.length);

    // decode from base64
    std::string encoded = [ciphertext UTF8String];
    CryptoPP::StringSource base64Decoder (encoded, true, new CryptoPP::Base64Decoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(ctext)));

    lcl_log(lcl_cCrypto, lcl_vDebug, @"Non-Encoded iv+ciphertext [size:%lu]:%s",sizeof(ctext),ctext.c_str());

    // get the IV from the beggining of the cryptogram
    std::string ivs = ctext.substr(0,CryptoPP::Serpent::BLOCKSIZE+5);

    lcl_log(lcl_cCrypto, lcl_vDebug, @"Recovered IV:%s",ivs.c_str());

    ::memcpy(iv, &ivs, ivs.size());

    // remove the IV from the cryptogram

    ctext.erase(0,CryptoPP::Serpent::BLOCKSIZE+5);

    lcl_log(lcl_cCrypto, lcl_vDebug, @"Non-Encoded ciphertext [size:%lu]:%s",sizeof(ctext),ctext.c_str());


    CryptoPP::Serpent::Decryption serpentDecryptor (key, CryptoPP::Serpent::MAX_KEYLENGTH);
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Decryption cbcSerpentDecryptor (serpentDecryptor, iv);

    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfSerpentDecryptor(cbcSerpentDecryptor, new CryptoPP::StringSink (plaintext));
    stfSerpentDecryptor.Put( reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>( ctext.c_str() ), ctext.length());
    stfSerpentDecryptor.MessageEnd();

    NSString *plainText = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:plaintext.c_str()];

    return plainText;
}
```

Notice I need to add 5 to the expected iv size to get the full IV. And then I get an error about "invalid PCKS#7 padding found . invalid ciphertext"

How to best manage the IV? (I would also like to add a HMAC to the iv+ciphertext (Encrypt-then-MAC)...

If I do this:

```
// get the IV from the beggining of the cryptogram
std::string ivs = ctext.substr(0,CryptoPP::Serpent::BLOCKSIZE);

lcl_log(lcl_cCrypto, lcl_vDebug, @"Recovered IV:%s",ivs.c_str());

::memcpy(iv, &ivs, ivs.size());

// remove the IV from the cryptogram

ctext.erase(0,CryptoPP::Serpent::BLOCKSIZE);
```

The logs will show a number of IV bytes still in the ciphertext, and generate a 'invalid ciphertext, size not a multiple of blocksize' exception.

Logs:

```
2013-12-01 17:59:37.747 App[413:70b] D Crypto:PSCryptoCore.mm:51:-[PSCryptoCore testSerpentEncryptonMechanism] Initial plaintext:Serpentine and black...
2013-12-01 17:59:37.748 App[413:70b] D Crypto:PSCryptoCore.mm:74:-[PSCryptoCore encryptUsingSerpentWithPlaintext:andKey:] Random IV:ç©ìùËß,¬<ÎΩ9ZÑ0 Û
2013-12-01 17:59:37.749 App[413:70b] D Crypto:PSCryptoCore.mm:87:-[PSCryptoCore encryptUsingSerpentWithPlaintext:andKey:] Non-Encoded ciphertext [size:4]:PÉò»ÓÃ”Ò¥ 1æIõ¶”Áˆ™8äºBmº†c
õ
2013-12-01 17:59:37.749 App[413:70b] D Crypto:PSCryptoCore.mm:93:-[PSCryptoCore encryptUsingSerpentWithPlaintext:andKey:] Non-Encoded iv+ciphertext [size:4]:ç©ìùËß,¬<ÎΩ9ZÑ0 ÛPÉò»ÓÃ”Ò¥ 1æIõ¶”Áˆ™8äºBmº†c
õ
2013-12-01 17:59:37.750 App[413:70b] D Crypto:PSCryptoCore.mm:54:-[PSCryptoCore testSerpentEncryptonMechanism] ciphertext:C42pk53opyzCPOu9FDlahDAg8wgBUIOYyO7M0/G0IDG+SZum0+f2qjiKvA4RQm28HaBjCps=
2013-12-01 17:59:37.750 App[413:70b] D Crypto:PSCryptoCore.mm:118:-[PSCryptoCore decryptUsingSerpentWithCiphertext:andKey:] Non-Encoded iv+ciphertext [size:4]:ç©ìùËß,¬<ÎΩ9ZÑ0 ÛPÉò»ÓÃ”Ò¥ 1æIõ¶”Áˆ™8äºBmº†c
õ
2013-12-01 17:59:37.752 App[413:70b] D Crypto:PSCryptoCore.mm:123:-[PSCryptoCore decryptUsingSerpentWithCiphertext:andKey:] Recovered IV:ç©ìùËß,¬<ÎΩ9ZÑ
2013-12-01 17:59:37.753 App[413:70b] D Crypto:PSCryptoCore.mm:131:-[PSCryptoCore decryptUsingSerpentWithCiphertext:andKey:] Non-Encoded ciphertext [size:4]:0 ÛPÉò»ÓÃ”Ò¥ 1æIõ¶”Áˆ™8äºBmº†c
õ
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type CryptoPP::InvalidCiphertext: StreamTransformationFilter: ciphertext length is not a multiple of block size
```

Notice that part of the IV is still in front of the ciphertext after I try to retireve it.. Why is this?

Answer (score 4):

Prepending the IV is exactly right. Why are you adding 5 to the blocksize? Decode from Base-64 to data. Pull the first BLOCKSIZE bytes off as the IV. Decrypt the remainder.

Comment: I did exactly that ... doesn't work ... I am adding 5 bytes, because it leaves 5 byte of the IV still prepended to the cipher text . I'll update the question

Comment: The best way to debug this is to output your IV and ciphertext in your encryptor (before putting them together). Then output them in your decryptor. They should of course be identical. That will tell you if you're messing up your encoding/decoding, concat, split, etc. Splitting this code up into small pieces could make it much easier to test.

Comment: I suspect the problem here is your use of std::string. Note that you have to reinterpret_cast it, which should be a tip-off it's the wrong type to be using. The raw data can include \0 in it, and you can't safely use that in calls to c_str. Encrypted data is a string of bytes, not a string of chars.

Comment: I suspected this... However all the examples of using Crypto++ use this kind of data type... So I'll have to convert a NSString to a byte array and then use that as the input to the cipher.. .. hmm

Comment: @user1028028 is there no way to use `NSData` instead? That's what I see in most code in objective-c

Comment: If your initial data is really a string, then it's easy to convert that to data. Just use `[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8String]`. You can then get a pointer to the raw data using `-bytes`. You should definitely never store random non-string data in an NSString (though I see you're using base64 encoding, which is fine). But if you're being forced to reinterpret_cast, you know you're probably fighting the framework.

Comment: I'm going to need to write the ciphertext and Iv to a TEXT file, in a JSON field... I don't think NSData will be written ok in such a manner

Comment: Converting the data into JSON should generally be done at the end, when you're encoding your JSON. You shouldn't try to make that part of your encryption routine. It just makes the encryption complicated. Keep data as data as long as you can; avoid converting back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it. 
This is the code

```
- (NSString *)encryptUsingSerpentWithPlaintext:(NSString *)plaintext andKey:(NSData *)keyData
{
    std::string ptext = [plaintext UTF8String];
    std::string ciphertext;

    byte key[ CryptoPP::Serpent::MAX_KEYLENGTH ], iv[ CryptoPP::Serpent::BLOCKSIZE ];

    CryptoPP::AutoSeededX917RNG<CryptoPP::Serpent> rng;
    rng.GenerateBlock(iv, CryptoPP::Serpent::BLOCKSIZE);

    std::string ivs(reinterpret_cast<char const *>(iv));
    lcl_log(lcl_cCrypto, lcl_vDebug, @"Random IV:%s",ivs.c_str());


    ::memcpy(key, keyData.bytes, keyData.length);


    CryptoPP::Serpent::Encryption serpentEncryptor (key, CryptoPP::Serpent::MAX_KEYLENGTH);
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcSerpentEncryptor (serpentEncryptor, iv);

    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfSerpentEncryptor(cbcSerpentEncryptor, new CryptoPP::StringSink (ciphertext),CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter::BlockPaddingScheme::ONE_AND_ZEROS_PADDING);
    stfSerpentEncryptor.Put( reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>( ptext.c_str() ), ptext.length() + 1);
    stfSerpentEncryptor.MessageEnd();

    lcl_log(lcl_cCrypto, lcl_vDebug, @"Non-Encoded ciphertext [size:%lu]:%s",sizeof(ciphertext),ciphertext.c_str());

    std::string finalCT;

    CryptoPP::StringSource base64Encoder (ciphertext, true, new CryptoPP::Base64Encoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(finalCT)));

    std::string ivB64;

    CryptoPP::StringSource base64IVEncoder (ivs , true, new CryptoPP::Base64Encoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(ivB64)));

    lcl_log(lcl_cCrypto, lcl_vDebug, @"IV base64[size:%lu]:%s",ivB64.length(),ivB64.c_str());

    finalCT = ivB64 + finalCT;

    lcl_log(lcl_cCrypto, lcl_vDebug, @"Cryptogram:%s",finalCT.c_str());

    // apply HMAC
    // TO DO

    NSString *cryptogram = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:finalCT.c_str()];

    return cryptogram;
}

- (NSString *)decryptUsingSerpentWithCiphertext:(NSString *)ciphertext andKey:(NSData *)keyData
{
    std::string ctext;
    std::string plaintext;

    byte key[ CryptoPP::Serpent::MAX_KEYLENGTH ], iv[ CryptoPP::Serpent::BLOCKSIZE ];

    ::memcpy(key, keyData.bytes, keyData.length);

    // decode from base64
    std::string encoded = [ciphertext UTF8String];

    // pull IV from ciphertext
    std::string ivs = encoded.substr(0,29);
    encoded.erase(0,29);

    CryptoPP::StringSource base64Decoder (encoded, true, new CryptoPP::Base64Decoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(ctext)));

    std::string iv_tmp;
    CryptoPP::StringSource base64IVDecoder (ivs, true, new CryptoPP::Base64Decoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(iv_tmp)));



    lcl_log(lcl_cCrypto, lcl_vDebug, @"Recovered IV[encoded]:%s",ivs.c_str());

    ::memcpy(iv, iv_tmp.data(), CryptoPP::Serpent::BLOCKSIZE);



    CryptoPP::Serpent::Decryption serpentDecryptor (key, CryptoPP::Serpent::MAX_KEYLENGTH);
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Decryption cbcSerpentDecryptor (serpentDecryptor, iv);

    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfSerpentDecryptor(cbcSerpentDecryptor, new CryptoPP::StringSink (plaintext), CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter::BlockPaddingScheme::ONE_AND_ZEROS_PADDING);
    stfSerpentDecryptor.Put( reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>( ctext.c_str() ), ctext.length());
    stfSerpentDecryptor.MessageEnd();

    NSString *plainText = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:plaintext.c_str()];

    return plainText;
}
```

I noticed that the IV in Base64 has length 29 ... I'm not sure that this is always the case.. could it be that for some  other 16 byte IV the length of the base64 string is different ?

Comment: 29 bytes is too long for Base64 encoding of 16 bytes. Base64 takes ceil(4n/3)(+optional padding) bytes to encode n bytes. So 16 bytes will take either 22 (unpadded) or 24 (padded) bytes.

Comment: I have no idea why... but the IV string is 29 chars